# Compatible WiFi adapter for ChromeOS

Tags: linux, wifi

I'm trying to install CloudReady on my 7 year old Lenovo laptop (Yoga 13). I was able to complete installation, however the inbuilt WiFi wasn't detected, and laptop doesn't have an Ethernet port.

I heard ChromeOS recently started supporting some external WiFi adapters. I tried Cisco Valet AM10, which I currently own and it din't get detected. I also tried replacing the inbuilt WiFi adapter, but the chip being proprietary, I cannot upgrade it.

Can anyone recommend an adapter that worked for you or think may work with ChromeOS

Comment: Found a list of working devices that other users reported. https://cloudreadykb.neverware.com/s/article/Unofficial-unsupported-but-WORKING-USB-wifi-dongle

Comment: hit another roadblock. Although Plugable USB-WIFINT was one of the compatible adapters, it wasn't detected after boot. I even tried disabling in-built Wifi adapters in BIOS.

Comment: Which version of the Plugable USB-WiFiINT?  Some don't work says https://www.aboutchromebooks.com/news/chromebooks-getting-support-for-usb-wi-fi-dongles/